# open server cannot create file c windows system32 drivers etc hosts отказано в доступе

Tags: windows, openserver, hosts

Работал себе опен сервер все было норм. Но вот запускаю и постоянный жёлтый флажок. Ошибка
open server cannot create file c windows system32 drivers etc hosts отказано в доступе
что было сделано?

1. attrib.exe -s -r -h -a C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
   не помогло
2. запускал от админа Опен сервер - не помогло
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. выставил максимальные права для папки с hosts (даже отдельно дал особые права) на папку etc не помогло
4. Ранее решил архивировать виндовс, чтобы меньшн места занимал - разорхивировал обратно не помголо
5. Добавил сайт в исключения виндовс дифендер. Не помогло.
   5.1) пересоздавал фаил hosts заливал в папку - не помогло.
6. Сейчас пролечиваю различными антивирусами, может что-то подцепил.
   У кого какие идеи? Работало все на этом же ПК.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пробовал https://github.com/OSPanel/SystemPreparationTool/releases не помогло. Зато помогла переустановка винды. Оказалось что система была сильно заражена и это была работа вируса - испорченные права к файлу. Откатился к контрольной точке системы.

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь официальной утилитой: https://github.com/OSPanel/SystemPreparationTool/releases

Она точно работает и поможет вам разблокировать файл HOSTS.

Если даже эта утилита не поможет, то значит ваш файл HOSTS защищает установленный в системе файрвол или антивирус. Тут поможет только грамотная настройка такого файрвола/антивируса, нужно снять защиту с файла HOSTS или разрешить к нему доступ для Open Server Panel.